# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar nuevas filas en datagridview, debajo de la fila seleccionada?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, datagridview, linq-to-sql

Actualmente he podido mostrar el resultado de una consulta  a la base de datos, en un datagridview. Lo nuevo que me gustaría a aprender es como muestro filas hijo, de bajo de la fila seleccionada. Si tengo una lista de semanas del año, al chequear o seleccionar una fila, que se visualicen las filas correspondientes a los días de la semana chequeada o seleccionada. Al deschequearla, que se oculten o contraigan.

Lo que quiero lograr es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. Diría que a tu pregunta le hace falta algo de código con el que muestras los datos, a forma de [mcve], pues eso aumentaría las probabilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas. Para más información lee [ask]. Un saludo.